# I need to pass two @RequestBody parameters into my REST API POST method. How can I achieve this and can I do it using DefaultHttpClient?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

My REST API method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/test/summary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
postSummaryData(@RequestBody String one, @RequestBody String two) { ... }
```

Comment: `class Foo { String one; String two; }` and then `postSummaryData(@RequestBody Foo foo)`?

Answer (score 0):

> @RequestMapping(value = "/api/test/summary/{one}/{two}", method = RequestMethod.POST) postSummaryData( @RequestParam String one, @RequestParam String two) {
> }

Also you can try below:

> @RequestMapping(value = "/api/test/summary", method = RequestMethod.POST) postSummaryData() {
>
> RequestAttributes attr = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
>
> HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)attr).getRequest();
>
> //  you can get param from this request
>
> }

Comment: Should not they be `@PathVariable` instead of the `@RequestParam`?